# Генерация строки

Tags: java, хеширование

Подскажите, как генерировать строку если есть алфавит:

```
String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
```

а строка должна сперва быть в 1 символ(и перечислить все возможные варианты), потом в 2 символа(тоже перечислить все возможные варианты) и так до `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 2):

Создаете цикл, который делает n(сколько вам символов нужно) итераций. Затем создаете рандомное целое число, входящее в диапазон 0-(alphabet.length-1). Затем приплюсовывайте предварительно созданной строке элемент массива alphabet под этим индексом (полученное ранд число). А в чем, собственно, проблема?